# Android date change automatically

Tags: android

I know this question has already been asked a couple of times here and i have searched them too but didn't find any ultimate solution.

how to call a method within an activity when date changed?

I have used broadcast receiver within the activity and have set the intentfilter like this

```
intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED");
```

this thing works only if im changing the date manually but it has to be like the method is called whenever the date is changed automatically.

i have also used

```
intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.TIME_TICK");
```

this one works perfectly but since this is time tick it happens in every minute and it gives a leaked window error saying

```
Activity com.example.testandroid.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.testandroid.MainActivity$1@4177ffe0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

how to overcome this??

any advice
or good suggestion
or good code is always welcome

thanks

Comment: try this android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"

Comment: @kettu tried it but it didn't work without time tick it is not working at all

Answer (score 1):

If you're registering a BroadcastReceiver registered from code in an activity/fragment/service (in `onCreate`/`onResume`) you must un-register it also from code (in `onDestroy`/`onPause`).

Comment: ok, i can unregister it onstop but i need the change whenever the date is changed not the time ticks every minute

please help me with that

Comment: Have you tried to use @kettu's suggestion: android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"? Also, using a BroadcastReceiver registered in the Manifest will make your app to not miss these notifications. If you keep the broadcast receiver in the activity when the activity is gone, then you'll miss the broadcast receiver notifications.

Comment: yes i have tried    android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"

but it didnt work without timer_tick

Answer (score 0):

Create service and register a BroadcastReceiver from it. Activity is destroyed when user closes it, and you need to keep receiver registered after it - only way to register such a receiver not from manifest is service

Comment: what I am actually upto is on date change if the application is running then the whole setcontentview will change on date change

 now this thing is only supposed to happen if the app is running if it is not running then why do i need to change the setcontentview each and every time date is changed so i don't need a service here

 only changing the view on date changed is enough i beleive,
 i hope i can make you understand what i intend to do..

Comment: if you need to catch date change only if your app runnig, the register receiver in onCreate and unregister it in onDestroy

Comment: right now im registering it onstart and im unregistering it onstop
 but tell me a way what to receive??
 intent-action datechange is not working properly
 time tick is checking every minute which is not required